# iphone-Changing float in second ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have two `ViewController` ,  `ViewController` and `getraenkeController`.

Now in `ViewController.h` is float named `getraenk`. I read that I should do it like this:

```
@property float getraenk;
```

and then in getraenkeController.m I should do this:

```
ViewController.getraenk
```

but that doesn't work.

I also importet the header from `ViewController.h`

Now how can I access the float from ViewController in `getraenkeController`?

Answer (score 1):

The float is added as a property to instances of the class, not the class itself. Once you create an instance of the class, then you'll be able to access the property.

```
ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] init...];
controller.getraenk = 4334.3;
```

Comment: It works now I can now do it like roher said. But it changes only in getraenkeView. in ViewController the float returns always 0 ?

Comment: @user3195648 Then you're probably setting the variable on a different instance of ViewController then the one that you're reading from.

Comment: it say's that the instance variable is protect ? :o
Edit: Now it works but it is always 0 again ...

Answer (score 0):

First declare public property 
if you use ARC :

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) float getraenk;
```

and then you must create object of ViewController class e.g.:

```
ViewController *obj = [ViewController new];
```

now you should get access to getraenk property e.g.:

```
obj.getraenk
```